# Detect Contact belong to Phone / Email Account iOS

Tags: ios, contacts

We know that contacts in iOS can be synced from `Google`, `iCloud` and `Phone`. Well, we can fetch bunch of Contacts using `Contacts.framework`, but I want to know which account it belongs to.

I mean, I need to differentiate Email and Phone synced contacts. Is there any way to do so?